# How to change a JSON array of objects into a multidimensional array in Python

Tags: python, json

I have code that will read a CSV file and convert it into an array of objects in JSON. What I need, however, is a multidimensional array (i.e., an array of arrays).

Here is my python code:

```py
import pandas
import json

df = pandas.read_csv('test.json', names=("en","th"))
df.to_json('test.json', orient='records')
with open('test.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(df.to_dict(orient='records'), f, indent=4)
```

That results in

```
[
    {
        "en": "en1",
        "th": "th1"
    },
    {
        "en": "en2",
        "th": "th2"
    }
]
```

But the result that I need is:

```
[
    [ "en","th"],
    [ "en1", "th1"],
    [ "en2", "th2"]
]
```

How can I alter my code to accomplish this?

Comment: Your expected output is not JSON, it's a multidimensional list. JSON will always be key-value pairs, and your expected output does not have that feature.

Comment: @gallen: You can model multidimensional arrays in JSON like this. That is 100% valid JSON according any of the various RFCs and standards that have been created around JSON.

Comment: @JeremyCaney If only I could downvote my own comment. Thank you for the clarification, this was something I was unaware of. TIL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have `df = pandas.read_csv('test.json', names=("en","th"))`, which is trying to use a method for reading CSV files to read JSON. This should be

```
df = pandas.read_json('test.json')
```

This will read in your data as JSON and populate the DataFrame. To write it out, you would update your second line to:

```
df.to_json('test.json', orient='values')
```

You can then remove your `with` clause. The full code would then be:

```
import pandas
import json

df = pandas.read_json('test.json')
df.to_json('test.json', orient='values')
```

Though, as written will overwrite your existing source file.

Thanks to [@Jeremy Caney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3025856/jeremy-caney) for the clarification on JSON validity.

Comment: Thanks you so much :)